# How can I declare 100 different named variables of the same type?

Tags: c++

I have a class named `Movies` and I have a hundred different movie names in an array. I want to make these Movies into a `Movies` type. How can I do that? I don't want to declare 100 individual variables.

I tried to make Movie name as 'Movies' type variable by using 'for-statement' but it doesn't work:

I declared a variable `movie_name`; it changes in the for loop into movie name.

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
    Movies movie_name = array[i];
    //...
}
```

I expected that 'Movies' type object named 'movie_name' being created, but it raise error.

How can I change this? Or do you have any other way to do this task??

What kind of technique when declaring many variables??

Comment: Create an array of `Movies` objects, where each of the elements (an object of type `Movies`) is created from one of the elements of the array of names (`array`).   Then your code can loop over the array of `Movies` instead of the array of names.     Better yet, use standard containers (for example, `std::vector<Movies>` and `std::vector<name>`) instead of raw arrays.

Comment: *"it doesn't work"* is no more useful than "I have a problem". A good problem description would inlude the expected and actual results, along with a [mre] demonstrating those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array (or list) of Movies objects and add new Movies objects to it (With 'new' operator) in the for loop.

Something like this:

```
Movies* moviesArray[array_size];
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    moviesArray[i] = new Movies(array[i]);
```

Note that you may need to define Movies constructor before code this.

Comment: Don't forget to `delete` each array element when you are done using it. Better to use `std::unique_ptr<Movies> moviesArray[array_size]` instead and let [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) manage the pointers for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes you are absolutely right, i totally forgot that about C++!

Comment: Why not simply create an array of objects instead of an array of pointers to objects? If you don't want to default-construct them all at once, prefer `std::vector`. Using `new` explicitly should be avoided in C++ if one doesn't code some low-level code.